# Can't remove empty space in PyQt UI

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm having a tough time trying to layout my PyQt UI. I have three 'QDockWidget' objects, two docked on the left and one docked on the right. With no controls added to any of them (other than a couple of images) the app looks like the following when first launched:

[image]

I then add a couple of buttons to the upper-left hand 'QDockWidget' by creating a class that inherits from 'QWidget' as follows:

```
class DataControls(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DataControls, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        overallVerticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        button1 = QPushButton("Button 1...", self)
        button2 = QPushButton("Button 2...", self)
        horizontalSubLayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        horizontalSubLayout1.addWidget(button1)
        horizontalSubLayout1.addWidget(button2)
        horizontalSubLayout1.addStretch(1)

        overallVerticalLayout.addLayout(horizontalSubLayout1)
        self.setLayout(overallVerticalLayout)

    def sizeHint(self):
        # Return an arbitrary preferred size for testing:
        return QSize(500, 100)
```

Then I assign this widget to the dock widget:

```
myDockWidget.setWidget(DataControls(self))
```

The above code generates the following:

[image]

Why has there been such a large amount of empty space added? I can "addStretch()" and move the two buttons up to the top but the massive amount of whitespace remains. Why is this and what is the proper way of getting rid of it? I'd like my QDockWidget to size itself to the controls that it contains. Thank you.

Comment: Set a minimum size for the widget in the bottom dock.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up doing just that, although it is a bit of a hack since I didn't want to constrain the minimum size. I can live with it for now.